# Trouble typing `zip`, and generally predicting when inference breaks in overloaded functions with generics

Tags: typescript

I sometimes have this kind of issue but I don't know exactly why the inference does not work.

In this case `zip` returns the correct type when applied directly, but not when applied through `pipe` and I have no idea why.

```js
declare const zip: {
    <A, B>(input: readonly [readonly A[], readonly B[]]): [A, B][],
    <A, B, C>(input: readonly [readonly A[], readonly B[], readonly C[]]): [A, B, C][],
    <A, B, C, D>(input: readonly [readonly A[], readonly B[], readonly C[], readonly D[]]): [A, B, C, D][],
    <A extends readonly any[]>(input: readonly A[]): A[0][][],
};

declare const pipe:  <A, B>(a: A, f: (a: A) => B) => B;

declare const x: [number[], string[], boolean[]];

const foo = pipe(x, zip);
//     ^? foo: any[][]
const bar = pipe(x, x => zip(x))
//     ^? bar: [number, string, boolean][]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gLwJYAcAueAbwCh5L4AeAQQBp4AhAPgApcV8BXDYuKMFQQAnvADaAoSlHxa4gLqMpwsU0UKAlMXENmCxfQpU6jJowDC7Tjz7wVMsZJCDVcw-ZfTZ6pZ9eO8BYa2hJ65kEGSsaUpsyWjAAi1ly8-F5uzgGy8n4OPh75YsF5GYGJITrhCfCJUUZUNLTwIAAeGCAowGj+3mJQKCKKKbbp2WK5ofIADFGGZAC+ANxkZKCQsAjI6Fj4BCDETWbsUMR6AGbEbKdymvAAvCzMd4-MK2vg0HCIqJjwrToUNwALYAIxAMA8mBgnAA5h5QUgkBAXCgNO9tn9zkiHvA9vgQGxWow8PhNCsAPQUxrwAB6AH4yJisKDYLj8YTif8Hk9SUTNJoyFSaQygA)
It's not that big of a deal, but it really puzzles me as it can leat to time wasted understanding why something does not compile, or efforts wasted trying to type something for it to not behave as intended in the end.

This `pipe` function by the way is an extract of the following, which works in most cases (not this one obviously), but is a little hard to look at

```js
const pipe: {
    <A>(
        a: A
    ): A
    <A, B>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B
    ): B
    <A, B, C>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C
    ): C
    <A, B, C, D>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D
    ): D
    <A, B, C, D, E>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E
    ): E
    <A, B, C, D, E, F>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E,
        j: (e: E) => F
    ): F
    <A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E,
        j: (e: E) => F,
        k: (f: F) => G
    ): G
    <A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E,
        j: (e: E) => F,
        k: (f: F) => G,
        l: (g: G) => H
    ): H
    <A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E,
        j: (e: E) => F,
        k: (f: F) => G,
        l: (g: G) => H,
        m: (h: H) => I
    ): I
    <A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(
        a: A,
        f: (a: A) => B,
        g: (b: B) => C,
        h: (c: C) => D,
        i: (d: D) => E,
        j: (e: E) => F,
        k: (f: F) => G,
        l: (g: G) => H,
        m: (h: H) => I,
        n: (i: I) => J
    ): J
}
```

You may think that, hey, with a mapped type you can come up with something like this (don't pay attention to the details)

```js
import { Lift, free, Init, Tail } from 'free-types';

declare const pipe: {
    <A,B>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B]>): B
    <A,B, C>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C]>): C
    <A,B, C, D>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D]>): D
    <A,B, C, D, E>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E]>): E
    <A,B, C, D, E, F>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E, F]>): F
    <A,B, C, D, E, F, G>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]>): G
    <A,B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]>): H
    <A,B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]>): I
    <A,B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(a: A, ...fns: Fns<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]>): J
};

type Fns<Fs extends [unknown, ...unknown[]]> = Lift<free.UnaryFunction, [Init<Fs>, Tail<Fs>]>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgGWAMxgGjmqBTPbASQDtgs4AVAQ2ABs4BfHKCEOAclwIFoYBPMHgDOHANwAoCQBM8AYzrV8cORBLD4YYEIBciCXENwAPAEFsAIQB8ACmp7zcAHQu06vQDF1xgNqOLALpWAJR6FgZGZpbYAMK29nCOLk5uwp7eftFwMUGh2RGGUXAWsdgAIvEO2Mmp6cK+-qVwZbl6ZQUmjdnl2ACilYnVru5wXvWZxU1lfa1wvR1FJd3NfdgeA0nDaaMZXTE9c2uzHgt7B71r2ADiG0MpI2MNWfsrh6PXs1enz+eXcFfYAASt2cWzqT0my2mbw81yBs0B30hL2hF3e-yBxBBNQeux+rzRsIxcEBxFmRCRSxRq3RAJJxGwAClsWCduMzgS-nTSXAiEzZoyJIxJBIBEI2cYPMI4HgAB4wPAkaTSnwAVxIAGsSBAAO4kO7qrW6kg+AJBOAAXhQ6Bgxm4eCcAFUSEp+B51XIYMA1NgfKRyJLhFZsDR6IGrEEpLIFEo8Co1BocHo7HoSKqQAAjPBQYKWqxwDRQYAkADmkmjimUqnU8BLyYSheLJdzFvzGYgEDoeGoJHL8krceriYAFvW9O3O92SC382nM9nTX2Y1WE-BgGO4HOs1BTTOCzAi6XFzJ+7H4zW4AArDeNo8BPcTrs948SIfwNAdy1wLRCGwAJmwNBsBLbBh2wYBsEvYJJAAehgoxDAAPQAfijU8VwvYBpD0MwNj3UwpDfOAMyUL8fzwf9AOA8DpGgiQ4IQuAUKAA)

but it is only going to work on monomorphic functions for some reason. I experimented with simpler designs, but basically at one point there will be one indirection that will loose the compiler and I can't really predict it. The longer/simpler version of `pipe` is the one you find in most FP libraries, and for good reason apparently.

Can you explain the `zip` situation? If you have thoughts on the more involved `pipe` version, feel free to share them.

Comment: Inference from functions with multiple call signatures generally only considers the last signature.  It’s a known design limitation of the language.  Does that suffice to address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does, maybe I should ask about pipe in another question and put more effort in a minimal implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Inference to overloaded functions gives you the last call signature with any generics erased.  It's a design limitation of TypeScript.

---

Since `zip()` is an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures, inferences involving it only consider the last call signature, instead of choosing the "appropriate" call signature that you'd get when you call `zip()` directly.  This is a known design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#50432](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50432) (among others).

So you get behavior similar to what would happen if `zip` were just

```
declare const zip: {
  <A extends any[]>(input: A[]): A[0][][],
};
```

Although in that case, you'd actually get a more specific result:

```
declare const x: [number[], string[], boolean[]];
const foo = pipe(x, zip);
//     ^? const foo: (string | number | boolean)[][]
```

But because you have overloads, the inference actually *erases* the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter when matching, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#52916](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52916) (which might be a bug but there's probably no good way to change it, at least according to that issue), and therefore the type parameter is replaced with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Meaning it actually behaves like

```
declare const zip: {
  (input: any[][]): any[][0][][],
};
```

which produces

```
const foo = pipe(x, zip);
//     ^? const foo: any[][]
```

as you've seen.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgILwAuArpnvoUUgCYTwYgBOy8A9sCjUkWAJYwAXIxYsAFAA9pw7mOABzAJTSAbvzGsA3EgD0JpCGABPJDF46kUMetB1eSAO5iMGNvyRi1MyyADwUSBAK1BDArFAW1gDaALoAfHJqMLTU0hQp2kh5AAzJKSkANMFIAL6GTLLsnDx8gsK2EhDSYeVIAELpILk9AGbScoOFmkgAvKl9U7N9dVWNXO4CQiJKSInAtGAARhDcFY7UqhqnB-z8GBCWKcnLshttwzcz7TAQij3iMJo6rIzLIkAA9AD8zGqTGYJGgcEQSAAymIwN4eDIWKtmkhXiJ-tICKCkGEIlEYnEElYUulMtlcvlGSUyslKrJavVsRw1i1Nl9OqSKD1+uMhkhRkgxZMZnNegs5c9uU11q0ttJdvsjic2WcLuorjc7g9kk8uUR8RKPtMBb9RBJAVUQbJIVyYXDwAjyEgAEr3Hw2YnK3l4tX2qRY2QZYBZHLU1kFSw00os0psqqclY83GWmAdLrCvoDcWS6UUBXzWVLc1sbOq-nbTWHY6nFRqA26663e7AR5Ki1h97+G15752-6O4HmF1Q6FMapAA)